# NGiNX content based loadbalancing

Tags: nginx, lua, load-balancing

Is there a possibility to configure nginx or tengin to handle traffic (balance it) depending on content of packet? for example:

- if request type is json

  - check if packet contain specific key, if does, forward to X
  - else forward to Y
- if request type is ogg

  - drop packet

for now i am aware that there is possibility to use lua or custom c module to handle it, but i have no idea how t do it.

Answer (score 0):

After a week of research i found out that it is almost impossible to create such a module or modify existing structures to handle such a task. NGiNX is very parallel in construction and there is a lot of unnecessary crap. For proxying requests i have chosen http_lua_module for nginx wich is easier to write and bypasses a LOT of problems with NGiNX engine. Also is more stable than native implementation in C.